# 3rd party sync method freezing the UI in .NET 4.7.2 WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I have a .NET 4.7.2 application using WPF MVVM. I am connecting to a robot using the provided library from the manufacturer. Unfortunately, their method that connects to the robot stops for 30 seconds when the IP parameter is faulty and this essentially freezes the UI.

I decided to use async/await to fix this issue, based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) I figured it is an I/O-Bound problem, but since the method I use to connect to the robot is sync, I couldn't await it. In the examples I saw they usually used async libraries at the first place and I couldn't find how to solve this problem, when a sync method is provided by 3rd party is freezing my UI.

The first code snippet didn't work, my UI stopped for 30 seconds when I tried to connect.

```cs
public async Task<bool> ConnectToRobot(string ip = "")
        {
            if (FanucController.IsConnected)
                return true;

            var result = await ConnectToFanuc(ip);

            return result;
        }

private Task<bool> ConnectToFanuc(string ip)
        {
            try
            {
                ((IRobot)FanucController).Connect(ip);
                // Other code for connection

                return Task.FromResult(true);
            }
            catch
            {
                return Task.FromResult(false);
            }
        }
```

Eventually I got around it by using the CPU-Bound example (second code snippet), however, this is not really a CPU bound problem, hence I'm not sure if this would cause problems in the future.

```cs
public async Task<bool> ConnectToRobot(string ip = "")
        {
            if (FanucController.IsConnected)
                return true;

            var result = await Task.Run(() => ConnectToFanuc(ip));

            return result;
        }

private bool ConnectToFanuc(string ip)
        {
            try
            {
                ((IRobot)FanucController).Connect(ip);
                // Other code for connection

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Is there a better way to solve this problem? Should I use something other than the async/await keywords?

Comment: *Cpu bound* or not, the way you plumbed up the original `ConnectToFanuc` is wrong, there is nothing *async* about this method apart from you returning a `Task`, if `Connect` has no `async` variant, you will have to *offload* it to another thread like you are doing, however this is still suspect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have completely misunderstood what .net async is doing.

`Task<T>` is an implementation of the Promise monad.

This can be in a variety of states (very simply).

- Not Complete
- Complete with Result
- Complete with Error

This is how the async/await engine does its magic. Methods can "complete" without a result.

`Task.FromResult` creates a Promise in the 2nd state. That means the the async/await engine has no chance to go off and do something else whilst waiting for the result.

One problem with the .net async await framework is the "Turtles/Async all the way down" problem. For async await to work properly, you need everything going down to be using the new fangled async/Task implementation (which is a pain since in general, that means reimplementing the entire library again).

A quick work-around for this is to use `Task.Run`. It is an acceptable workaround, for 3rd party libraries which do not support async/await.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Task.Run` to make asynchronous wrappers around synchronous methods is generally considered a bad practice unless you want to offload the current thread to prevent it from freezing while waiting for the synchronous method complete.

So since `ConnectToFanuc` is obviously not asynchronous in this case, it is a viable workaround to use `await Task.Run` to call it.

Please refer to [this blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html) for more information about this.